# direct use of Futures in Akka

Tags: scala, akka, future

I am not able to create a Future as explained [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/scala/futures.html). It says you can create a `Future` directly using the following code:

```
import akka.dispatch.Await
import akka.dispatch.Future
import akka.util.duration._

val future  = Future {
  "Hello" + "World"
}
val result = Await.result(future, 1 second)
```

Using the exact same code, I get an errormessage, saying: `error: could not find implicit value for parameter executor: akka.dispatch.ExecutionContext`. All I can find about the `ExecutionContext` is, that you can "do stuff" with it. In the documentation, the only line I found was:

```
implicit val ec = ExecutionContect.fromExecutionService(yourExecutionServiceGoesHere)
```

But this was not usefull to me. Has anyone any suggestion on that topic for me? How can I create a new `Future` without asking an `Actor`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have an `ActorSystem` then it will have an `ExecutionContext` which can be used here. It must be `implicit`, unless you pass it explicitly to the `Future.apply` method.

For the purposes of demonstration, if you just want to see how this works in the REPL:

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("MySystem").dispatcher
```

(There is also an implicit conversion `ActorSystem => ExecutionContext` on the `ExecutionContext` object.)

To create modular code, without creating a context just before the point of use, consider making the context an abstract member of a trait:

```
trait MyFutures {
  implicit val context: ExecutionContext

  def helloFuture: Future[String] = Future { "hello" + "world" }
}
```

Comment: To be very clear, to create an ActorSystem just to gain access to an ExecutionContext is very bad practice, as who is shutting down the ActorSystem, and when? IF you aren't using Actors, there is no need for an ActorSystem.

Comment: Indeed, I should make it more clear that the first line of code isn't what you would do in an application.

Answer (score 3):

Your code does not compile because you are writing illegal Scala code: the signature of `Future.apply` clearly states that. I assume you understand that you are calling the apply method of the companion object of the trait Future, which is the following:

```
object Future extends java.lang.Object with scala.ScalaObject {
  def apply[T](body : => T)(implicit executor : akka.dispatch.ExecutionContext) : akka.dispatch.Future[T] = { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

Since you do not have an implicit `ExecutionContext` available when calling `Future.apply`, you get a compilation error. It's the same as calling a method which receives two parameters if you provide just one.

The problem of how the `ExecutionContext` can be created is different, and you can find the answer in Akka Documentation:

> In order to execute callbacks and operations, Futures need something
>   called an ExecutionContext, which is very similar to a
>   java.util.concurrent.Executor. if you have an ActorSystem in scope, it
>   will use its default dispatcher as the ExecutionContext, or you can
>   use the factory methods provided by the ExecutionContext companion
>   object to wrap Executors and ExecutorServices, or even create your
>   own.