# could not find implicit ...: akka.http.server.RoutingSetup

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

While playing with, akka-http experimental 1.0-M2 I am trying to create a simple Hello world example.

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.Http
import akka.http.model.HttpResponse
import akka.http.server.Route
import akka.stream.FlowMaterializer
import akka.http.server.Directives._

object Server extends App {

  val host = "127.0.0.1"
  val port = "8080"

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-testing-system")
  implicit val fm = FlowMaterializer()

  val serverBinding = Http(system).bind(interface = host, port = port)
  serverBinding.connections.foreach { connection ⇒
    println("Accepted new connection from: " + connection.remoteAddress)
    connection handleWith Route.handlerFlow {
      path("") {
        get {
          complete(HttpResponse(entity = "Hello world?"))
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Compilation fails with `could not find implicit value for parameter setup: akka.http.server.RoutingSetup`

Also, if I change

```
complete(HttpResponse(entity = "Hello world?"))
```

with

```
complete("Hello world?")
```

I get another error: `type mismatch; found : String("Hello world?") required: akka.http.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With research I was able to understand the issue to be lack of `Execution Context`. To solve both the issue I needed to include this:

```
implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher
```

Looking into `akka/http/marshalling/ToResponseMarshallable.scala` I see `ToResponseMarshallable.apply` requires it which returns a `Future[HttpResponse]`.

Also, in `akka/http/server/RoutingSetup.scala`, `RoutingSetup.apply` needs it.

May be akka team just needs to add some more `@implicitNotFound`s. I was able to find not exact but related answer at: [direct use of Futures in Akka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275878/direct-use-of-futures-in-akka) and [spray Marshaller for futures not in implicit scope after upgrading to spray 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809984/spray-marshaller-for-futures-not-in-implicit-scope-after-upgrading-to-spray-1-2/19820230#19820230)

Answer (score 2):

Well found - this problem still exists with Akka HTTP 1.0-RC2, so the code for that now must look like this (given their API changes):

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.server._
import akka.http.scaladsl._
import akka.stream.ActorFlowMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Sink, Source}
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse
import Directives._
import scala.concurrent.Future

object BootWithRouting extends App {

  val host = "127.0.0.1"
  val port = 8080

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-testing-system")
  implicit val fm = ActorFlowMaterializer()
  implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

  val serverSource: Source[Http.IncomingConnection, Future[Http.ServerBinding]] =
    Http(system).bind(interface = host, port = port)

  serverSource.to(Sink.foreach {
    connection =>
      println("Accepted new connection from: " + connection.remoteAddress)
      connection handleWith Route.handlerFlow {
        path("") {
          get {
            complete(HttpResponse(entity = "Hello world?"))
          }
        }
      }
  }).run()
}
```